# SQLite/Python same variable name and column name problem

Tags: python, sqlite

So i am trying to work out how to use sql lite with python by setting up a simple database full of different students and their courseworks and scores etc....
I am writing a function that updates my database for the score a student got given their id, unit id and the mark. However I have a column in my assignments table that is called mark!

This is what I thought would work....

```
def mark_assignment(database, studentid, assessmentid, mark):
    mark = score
        access_database(database,"UPDATE assignments SET mark = score, marked = 1  WHERE assignments.studentid = studentid AND assignments.assessmentid = assessmentid ")
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add placeholders in your SQL line while executing.

> str.format() is one of the string formatting methods in Python3, which
> allows multiple substitutions and value formatting. This method lets
> us concatenate elements within a string through positional formatting.
> Each parameter in the format function **replaces the corresponding placeholder in the string.**

Here is a small example for the same:

```
#Code
first_name = "Heeth" 
last_name = "Jain" 
print("Hello {} {}".format(first_name, last_name))

#Output
Hello Heeth Jain
```

SQL Statement would look like:

```
"UPDATE assignments SET mark = {}, marked = 1  WHERE assignments.studentid = {} AND assignments.assessmentid = {}".format(mark, studentid, assessmentid)
```

Since you are using a single table in this command, you can also change the statement as follows (I just changed ***assignments.studentid*** to ***studentid*** and so on:

```
"UPDATE assignments SET mark = {}, marked = 1  WHERE studentid = {} AND assessmentid = {}".format(mark, studentid, assessmentid)
```

So Finally, after the changes, it should be something like this:

```
def mark_assignment(database, studentid, assessmentid, mark):
    statement = "UPDATE assignments SET mark = {}, marked = 1  WHERE studentid = {} AND assessmentid = {}".format(mark, studentid, assessmentid)
    access_database(database, statement)
```

**Note:
In real-life situations, using str.format() is a bad idea as it can be misused using SQL Injection.** But since we only know about this single function and not the entire code, formatting can help here. Adding placeholders like **?** are the better options in those cases. Reference: https://realpython.com/prevent-python-sql-injection/